# Type-stability in Julia for creating SVector with ::Function

Tags: julia, type-stability

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to write code in a type-stable manner.
I know that some limitations, such as `::Function` and `::Val{}` arguments are an issue, and so I'm trying to figure out the best way of going around those.
I'm still deep into the learning phase, so please feel free to provide as much information and comments as you feel like.

As part of that, I was trying to create an `SVector` that is type-stable, however I keep getting it wrong. here is a MWE (and pardon the stupid names for functions and variables, I tried to maitain the actual structure of the code while removing meaningful content), where the output is `SVector{_A, Float64} where _A`. How do I get a proper `SVector` here? Feel free to modify the code as you please, as long as the function order and structure remains.

Supporting functions:

```
using StaticArrays
@inline function HyperTanDistribSymm(α::T,Lx::T=one(T)) where T<:AbstractFloat
    return x -> convert(T,0.5)*Lx*( one(T) - tanh( α*(one(T)-convert(T,2.0)*x) ) / tanh(α) )
end

function GenerateVec(L::TF, indxrng::AbstractUnitRange{TI}, ntotal::TI=length(indxrng), Stretchfun::Function=x::TF->x::TF, nghost::TI=1) where {TI<:Integer, TF<:AbstractFloat}
    nterms::TI=2*nghost+length(indxrng)+one(TI)
    return SVector{nterms,TF}( map( Stretchfun,L*convert.(TF, indxrng[1]-one(TI)-nghost:indxrng[end]+nghost)/convert(TF, ntotal)  ) )
end


function madness(varD::TF, indx::AbstractUnitRange{TI}, varN::TI, stretch::Function, nghost::TI) where {TF<:AbstractFloat, TI<:Integer}
    testvar=GenerateVec(varD, indx, varN, stretch, nghost)
    nterms::TI=length(testvar)-one(TI)
    diffvar=SVector{nterms,TF}( diff(testvar) )
end
```

And running examples:

```
using Cthulhu
@descend_code_warntype madness(1.0, 1:6, 6, x->x, 1)
@descend_code_warntype madness(2.0, 2:8, 10, HyperTanDistribSymm(2.20,6.0), 2)
```

as `GenerateVec` returns `SVector{nterms::Int64,TF::Type{Float64}}::Type{SVector{_A, Float64}} where _A`.
I will comment that I tried other versions, including the use of `Val` approach on something on the lines of:

```
@inline CreateSVector(input::Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{T}) where {T<:Number} = CreateSVector(Val(length(input)), input)
@inline CreateSVector(::Val{N}, input::Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{T}) where {N,T<:Number} = SVector{N,T}( input )
```

this is just one example, I also tried using `N` just as a regular `N<:Integer` input and such. All result in the same issue.

Note: I have read around and figured that possibly the use of Tuples pass arguments and set sizes might be a solution - if that is the case, why?

Comment: Just as a side comment: if you see various conversions that seem out-of-place, that is me trying to verify that everything else is type-stable and not causing issues. Originally they were not there (as it was seen as type-stable)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit more than necessary. You could do `Lx * (1 - tanh(α*(1 - 2*x))/ 2tanh(α)`. If you are concerned about unwanted float promotion, just use integers.

Comment: There's a bit much going on to analyze on a phone, but what will definitely _not_ work is `SVector{nterms,TF}` where `nterms` is a runtime value. It must be a compile time constant to achieve type stability.

Comment: As DNF said, `SVector`s are for compile-time length known vectors. If the `SVector` casts are removed, the functions become type-stable (just checked this).

Comment: @DanGetz, the thing is, I want it to end up as an `SVector` for other math operations later. These used to be Tuples originally (and I think it was type-stable then), but since the output is continuously used I want the benefit of the LinearAlegbra implemented operations. I guess I can make this an MVector, if that helps, but I see no point in doing so.

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs `MVector`s are _also_ StaticArrays, and their lengths must be known at compile time for type stability. The same goes for tuples, their lengths must be known at compile time, you cannot calculate their lengths at runtime, and still preserve type stability. Consider using regular `Vector`s.

Answer (score 1):

You might find a text I wrote useful in your quest for understanding type stability:
https://www.juliabloggers.com/writing-type-stable-julia-code/

But the short version is as follows:
a) the type of a `StaticVector` depends on its length.
b) type stability means that types (and so `StaticVector`s') length are defined at compile time
c) so the length must be either hard coded, or be given as a type parameter.  Examples, where the parameter is called `VecLen`:

```
... ::Val{VecLen}}...) where {VecLen}
```

or

```
... v::StaticArray{VecLen,Float64}...) where {VecLen}
```

You want type stability 'cause you want speed 'cause you're in a loop.  If you can compute VecLen outside the loop (see the concept of barrier function) and pass it down to your function (using `Val`, or other technique) you win.

If you cannot precompute `VecLen` (e.g. because it changes at each iteration) then we are busted, you will not get type stability.  You would then `StaticArrays` are not for you today.

I hope this helps!

: )

Philippe